# Apply animation if location.href.indexOf ends with #name - not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can somebody please explain where I am going wrong here. When somebody visits /page.php#mobile from a hyperlink on the homepage I'd like one of the relevant actions to take place

```
$(function() {
    if ( document.location.href.indexOf('#mobile') > -1 ) {
        $('#div1').animate({ backgroundColor: "#f00" }, "slow");
        $('#div1').animate({ backgroundColor: "#fff" }, "slow");
    else if ( document.location.href.indexOf('#pc') > -1 ) {
        $('#div2').animate({ backgroundColor: "#f00" }, "slow");
        $('#div2').animate({ backgroundColor: "#fff" }, "slow");
    }
});
```

Right now nothing seems to be working?

Comment: `window.location.hash`

Comment: Have you add debugging statements to see where it fails?

Comment: Do you have the background color plugin for animations?

Comment: @epascarello yeah I have it included. I'll try `window.location.hash`